# Dynamic Webservices project -- can only connect over localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, git, web-services

I'm running a RESTful webservice created in Eclipse Java EE using TomCat 7.0. I test it using a web browser. It will connect over the localhost, but not with the remote IP. It used to work with an IP, and then I moved my project to a Git repository so I could upload it to Github. Now it's not working for an IP. Not really sure what's up.

Any ideas? Firewalls are off too.

Bonus: I also have the small red x error icon on my project. I can't find any errors and it compiles fine and works fine as long as it's localhost. How the heck do I get rid of the x icon?

Edit: Works with a local IP. I was testing this on a college network earlier. Now I'm on a home network. Any comments?

Comment: OK! Solved it! My home network's router needs some configuring. Probably need to forward a port or something. This isn't something I need to do (and it's possibly not my router cough) so let's consider this solved! THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following article helps :
 www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere

Incase you also have trouble accessing via localhost refer to all the answers for this post:
stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8085

The question is missing many details like logs.. url and configuration for tomcat to give you a specific answer

Comment: That's great. I'll have a look.